# Overriding virtual functions and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions

I'm having trouble fully understanding overriding virtual functions in C++ and what exactly happens when such functions are called.I'm reading PPP using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup and he provides following example to show off overriding and virtual functions:

```
struct B {
    virtual void f() const { cout<<"B::f; }
    void g() const { cout << "B::g"; }        //not virtual
};

struct D:B {
        void f() const { cout<<"D::f"; } //overrides B::f
        void g() { cout<<"D::g"; }
};

struct DD:D {
        void f() { cout<<"DD::f"; }
        void g() const { cout<<"DD::g";}    
};

void call(const B& b) {
    //a D is kind of B, so call() can accept D
    //a DD is kind of D and a D is a kind of B, so call() can accept a DD
    b.f();
    b.g();
}

int main() {
    B b;
    D d;
    DD dd;

    call(b);
    call(d);
    call(dd);

    b.f();
    b.g();
    d.f();
    d.g();
    dd.f();
    dd.g();
}
```

Output: `B::f B::g D::f B::g D::f B::g B::f B::g D::f D::g DD::f DD::g`

I understand how call(b) outputs `B::f B::g` that is straightforward.

Now `call(d)`. I don't quite understand why but it seems that `call()` can take derived classes of `B` as an argument. Ok. So in `call()` , `b.f()` becomes `d.f()`, since `D::f` overrides `B::f` . Indeed output says `D::f`. But `D::g` doesn't override `B::g` and for the reasons I can't understand it seems to me that `D::g` is having no effect when `call(d)` is executed -- outputs `B::g` in this case.

Next, we execute `call(dd)` which outputs `D::f B::g` . Applying the same logic(?) as above it's clear that `DD::f` doesn't override `D::f` -- not const -- and `DD::g` doesn't override neither `D::g` nor `B::g` since neither are `virtual`.

What happens next bewilders me. Each individual call of `b.f()` , `b.g()` , `d.f()`, `d.g()`, `dd.f()`, `dd.g()` outputs result as if overriding didn't exist at all!
For example, how could `d.g()` output `D::g` when just seconds ago `d.g()` in call() output `B::g` ?
Another, how could `dd.f()` output `DD::f` when in `dd.f()` in `call()` output `D::f` ?

It's safe to say I'm missing something big here, and for that I need help.

Comment: dont you realize a pattern? For virtual the method is chosen based on the actual type of the object. For non virtual the method to call is chosen statically. What bewilders you is exactly the difference between virtual and non virtual methods

Comment: To  be honest, this code confuses me, and I've been programming in C++ for over 30 years. The fact is, Srtroustrup is not a good teacher.

Comment: @ user463035818, I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what "non virtual the method to call is chosen statically" means. How are virtual methods chosen based on the actual type of the object exactly?

@Neil Butterworth, Actually I think the text is great and he takes the time to explain things properly. But sometimes he saves things for the later chapters or uses them without explanation but says so explicitly (This will become clear later etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be patient and read this to get answers to your questions.

Inheritance is a concept in which object of a class inherits the properties and behaviour of object of another class.

#### Basic Introduction

- Parent class is also called as base class or super class.
- Child class is also called as derived class or subclass.
- An object of a derived class can be referenced through the base class.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
int main() {
  Base *b = new Derived(); // This is completely valid
  return 0;
}
```

#### Method Overriding in C++

Let's take a basic example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
  void display() { cout << "Base display called\n"; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void display() { cout << "Derived display called\n"; }
};
int main() {
  Base b;
  b.display();
  Derived d;
  d.display();
  Base *bptr = &d;
  bptr->display();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base display called
Derived display called
Base display called
```

Now, from the above example you might have guessed that the derived class overrides the base class but this is not the case. The output (3rd line) shows that the base class function is called because the function is not virtual.

#### Virtual functions in C++

You can make any function of the class virtual by adding the "virtual" keyword at the start of the function.

Lets consider the virtual function example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
  virtual void display() { cout << "Base display called\n"; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void display() { cout << "Derived display called\n"; }
};
int main() {
  Base b;
  b.display();
  Derived d;
  d.display();
  Base *bptr = &d;
  bptr->display();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base display called
Derived display called
Derived display called
```

By the above example(line 3 of the output), it is clear that you can achieve method overriding by using the virtual function mechanism in C++.

#### What is the effect of making a function virtual?

The difference between a normal function and a virtual function is that a normal function is resolved at compile time, also known as static binding, whereas the virtual function is resolved at run time, also known as dynamic binding or late binding. Which method to call (base class display or derived class display method) is resolved at run time since the base class display function is made virtual. You can dive deep into the virtual function mechanism by reading about v-table.

#### Answers to questions

1. call(d). I don't quite understand why but it seems that call() can take derived classes of B as an argument.

   - A derived class object can be referenced by a base class
2. But D::g doesn't override B::g and for the reasons I can't understand.

   - Because g() is not virtual in base class. Only virtual functions can be overridden. v-table has entries to only virtual functions so that they can be overridden at run time.
3. call(dd)

   - Since f() in DD is a non-const function, therefore f() (non-const f() in DD) is not an overridden method of the parent class D. And since it is being referenced by Base class B, calling b.f() would call the const f() which is being overridden by D. Thus D::f gets printed.
   - If f() was a const method in DD then the following would have happened:
     When f() gets called, the function is searched first in the base class B,
     since f() is virtual, using the v-table pointer, the f() function being overridden in derived class D is resolved. But since f() is not virtual in class D, the overridden f() in DD can't be resolved. Hence D::f gets printed.
     But for g(), the base class itself doesn't have virtual g(), so the overridden functions in their derived classes can't be resolved. Hence, B::g get printed.
4. The above polymorphism has happened because the derived classes were referenced by their base classes(parent classes), but in the last calls, there is no such thing. All the objects are referenced by their respective classes, and hence their appropriate methods are being called.

One basic logic to think about this is that the function is first looked up in the referencing class, and if it is virtual then the function will be searched in derived classes(if the object being referred is a child class). If the derived classes override, then the derived method will be called, else the base method will be called. You can further extend the concept applied to the base class, to the derived class as well like the check whether the function is virtual or not and then if the function is virtual and the object is derived(child of the derived, grandchild of the base) and so on.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: To be honest, I have yet to cover pointers so your example is not exactly clear to me. But so far I think I get the basics of overriding/virtual functions.
Could you make sense of my questions in original post?

Comment: @bruneleski in order to make sense of your question you got to understand what virtual tables are and how the dynamic polymorphism is related to that. if I wanted to shorten the answer I gave below, it would be that non-virtual functions doesn't exist in the virtual table and therefore, can not take the advantages of the runtime polymorphism.

Comment: @Yucel_K, Oh I see, in the meantime I read about virtual tables and virtual pointers and what you are saying is becoming much clearer.
Thanks a ton!

Comment: There's one mistake in this answer. DD::f() is not an override of B::f() or D::f() because it has a different signature. B::f() and D::f() are both const methods, whereas DD::f() does not. That is why it is not called in call(dd). If DD::f() were marked const, then it would be called by call(dd).

Answer (score 0):

*For example, how could d.g() output D::g when just seconds ago d.g() in call() output B::g ?*

when you pass a derived object as pointer or reference of type base class, you are keeping its polymorphic properties. however, that doesn't mean you can still access the non-virtual functions of the derived class.

consider this example,

```
B *bp;
bp = &d;
bp->f();
bp->g();
```

when `bp->g()` executed, `g` function of the `b` will be called.

Comment: I see. So when I call a method let's say call(d), it can see only members of B since that is what argument is referring to after all.
I think I got this. Thanks.

Comment: @bruneleski yes that's correct. unless the virtual keyword is used as in your example like how you done with. `virtual void f()` of `b` class .  if the `virtual void f()` is also overridden like how your `d` is doing and if `d` is passed as a reference to call ( `call(d);` ).  then the entry of the virtual table pointer in the reference parameter `const B& Ref ` will point to `void f() const` of `d`. so whenever you call `Ref.f()` it will be the `virtual void f()` of `d`. the term for this is called **runtime polymprhism** or **dynamic polymorphism**